# Why paragraph overlap to the panel-heading?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I tried to add HTML paragraph beside of `<strong>{{ $result->username }}</strong>` the paragraph overlap to the panel-heading. This is the output when I didn't add the paragraph.Can anyone tell me why I get this output?

**Without paragraph**

[image: Without paragraph]

**With paragraph**
[image: With paragraph]

I didn't add to my code the limitation of paragraph I just testing the output.

**View**

```
<div class = "col-md-8">

    <form class = "form-inline">

        <div class = "panel panel-default">

            <div class = "panel-body" style = "height: 500px">

                <div class = "row">

                    <div class = "col-xs-12">

                        <div class = "panel panel-default">

                            @foreach ($messageResult as $result)
                            <div class = "panel panel-heading-inbox" style = "height: 20px">

                                <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>

                                <strong>{{ $result->username }}</strong>

                                <div class = "btn-toolbar pull-right">

                                    <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-default">Open</button>
                                    <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-danger">Delete</button>

                                </div>

                            </div>
                            @endforeach 

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your `btn-toolbar` has `pull-right`. Floating items don't take up space unless their parent has overflow: hidden. **Also remove the inline height of 20px.**

```
.panel-heading-inbox {
  line-height: 34px; /*vertically align adjust to your need or delete it*/
  overflow: hidden;
}
```